# How do I set a usercontrol as datatemplate by default?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have a wpf app that displays a window on startup.
The `XAML` for the Window contains a Data template that is set based on `datatype`, such as:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainControlVM}">
        <views:MainControl />
    </DataTemplate>
```

However, I need to display a `usercontrol` at startup. The code above works everywhere except at start-up. I think I need to set a default value for `datatype` but I dont know how to do that. I can set it through commands, but I don't know how to fire a command at start-up either.

**How do I set a `usercontrol` as data template by default?**

Comment: DataTemplate is a visual representation of data. Where are you setting data? `It works everywhere` - Can you add more details?

Comment: By everywhere I mean apart from the window displayed at startup. I can click an entry in my menu which fires a command which sets the DataTemplate, thus displaying a usercontrol. Then in that usercontrol theres a button which I click to set the DataTemplate to another value etc

Comment: `Sets the DataTemplate` - where?

Comment: DataTemplate gets set through the command process I described, the actual code (which the example in my post is a part of) is located in the XAML file for the startup window. The datatype refers to my CurrentViewModel, a variable located in the VM for the startup window. So DataTemplate only gets set in the startup window, specifically in Window.Resources tag.